# AngularJS integration with serverside MVC Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, angularjs, server-side

I have created an app with AngularJS. Now for fallback and some extendible functionality I want to integrate it with some other MVC framewrok like JSF2, Struts2, Spring MVC, ruby on rails etc. Can any one suggest me whether is it possible to do this. Which frameowrk should I go with. Can you please share some tutorial/example. It has to be RESTful; so that I can control the flow...

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Angular is not tight on any server side solution.
You can use whatever technology you want to build your RESTful services.

Comment: So in this case can i render my view from server or can i control my view from server? If yes then I have to write a logic for interating thats response object in view which we normally do in controller.

Answer (score 1):

I've written about [using AngularJS with Node.js](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html) via the Express.js server-side MVC library. As Florian noted, you can use any backend you'd like, but Node.js is my personal favorite.

Comment: but if u want to use node.js in that case we have to download additional installable for windows...which is not the case with other JS framework...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You'd have to download and install Ruby, and then install RoR through Rubygems. You'd have to download the JDK, and then Spring MVC. How is Node.js different here? It is completely separate from your client-side code.